# NativeScript AdMob plugin - crash the app on emulator or on playground: Cannot read property 'getRewardedVideoAdInstance' of undefined

Tags: nativescript

I've created a nativescript with angular (drawer template) app and everything works fine. 
Using the command `tns run android --bundle` the app was successfully installed and runned on the Pixel 2 emulator.

The problem was after I installed the admob plugin, using the command `tns plugin add nativescript-admob`. Immediately app crashed on the emulator[image: app crashed after admob plugin was installed].

Bellow the package.json to proff the installation of the admob plugin on my app.

```
...
"nativescript-admob": "^4.0.1",
...
```

Nevertheless, I've continued following instructions from here: https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-admob

so my AndroidManifest.xml it looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="__PACKAGE__"
android:versionCode="10000"
android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    **<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917" />**

    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
</application>
```

and the browse.component.ts it looks like that:

On the emulator, the app continues to crash, 
However, using the nativescript playground (tns preview) the app does not crash but it gives the error: LOG from device Galaxy S9: Error in admob.preloadRewardedVideoAd: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRewardedVideoAdInstance' of undefin
LOG from device Galaxy S9: admob preloadRewardedVideoAd error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRewardedVideoAdInstance' of undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as admob from "nativescript-admob";

@Component({
    selector: "Browse",
    templateUrl: "./browse.component.html"
})
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // Init your component properties here.
        admob.preloadRewardedVideoAd({
            testing: true,
            iosAdPlacementId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXX/YYYYY2", // add your own
            androidAdPlacementId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", // add your own
            keywords: ["keyword1", "keyword2"], // add keywords for ad targeting
        }).then(
             () => {
                console.log("RewardedVideoAd preloaded");
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("native-admob preloadRewardedVideoAd error: " + error);
            }
        )
    }

    onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any plugin that relies on native dependency do not work with Playground, ad mob plugin has a native dependency. Please share the logs you see in Emulator console upon crash.

Comment: Hi Manoj, Unfortunately, that's my problem, no log. Emulator console? Please have a look at the image URL: http://ittradconsulting.eu/public-share/emulator-console.png

Comment: Try Android Device Monitor, that usually prints all sort of exceptions from connected device / emulator.

Comment: Please find the log from IOS emulator: 
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Successfully transferred all files on device D840681F-88D2-42B5-9671-8719297AC746.
Restarting application on device D840681F-88D2-42B5-9671-8719297AC746...
(RunningBoardServices) [com.apple.runningboard:connection] Identity resolved as application<org.nativescript.helptohelp>
CONSOLE INFO file:///node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/hot.js:3:0: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:25638:0: .

Comment: NativeScript caught signal 6.
Native Stack:
1   0x103801481 sig_handler(int)
2   0x7fff5245b42d _sigtramp
3   0x1
4   0x7fff5234ba5c abort
5   0x7fff502497f8 __cxa_bad_cast
6   0x7fff502499c7 demangling_unexpected_handler()
7   0x7fff513fbd7c _objc_terminate()
8   0x7fff50256e97 std::__terminate(void (*)())
9   0x7fff50256e39 std::terminate()
10  0x7fff5223f7cd _dispatch_client_callout
11  0x7fff5224bc9b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
12  0x7fff23bd4049 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
13  0x7fff23bceca9 __CFRunLoopRun
14  0x7fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecif

Comment: JS Stack:
UIApplicationMain([native code])
at run(file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.js:312:0)
at file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:210:0
at file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:111:0
at file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:91:0
at file:///app/bundle.js:591:144
at ./main.ts(file:///app/bundle.js:596:34)
at __webpack_require__(file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
at checkDeferredModules(file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:

Comment: Your crash is with iOS / Android, because your OP points everything about Android but your crash log looks like form iOS?

Comment: No, the point is, not being able to generate log using Android Device Monitor, I give a try using IOS emulator (and XCode) so that the error I received whenever I lunch the app on IOS emulator. So like a conclusion, the AdMob plugin it crash the app on both emulators android and ios.

Comment: The big problem here, something you can try on your environment, is that the crash happens whenever you install the plugin. So in order to reproduce this crash is enough to install the admob plugin and relaunch the app on both emulators.

Comment: Finally some log: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: org.nativescript.help2help, PID: 8772 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6242)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentPr

Comment: SOLVED !! 
ANDROID:
1) Add this to App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml (code 3347511713)
...
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
...

2) When initialisation of the firebase instead uses another test code(5224354917):
firebase.admob.preloadRewardedVideoAd({
                    iosAdPlacementId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXX/YYYYY2", // add your own
                    androidAdPlacementId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", // add your own
                    
                }